# Left ArtinianRings 3

Tags: abstract-algebra

we know that if R as a ring is left artinian then ring R has a minimal left ideal and left socle of R is nonempty.

now i wanna know can we prove this:

if R is left artinian ring then right socle of R is nonempty.

how can i find a relation between them?

tank you for your help